# How Flutter(Dart) can build apps for several platforms technically?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, mobile-application

I've read Flutter documents about supporting multi-platform applications but I didn't understand how technically it is possible?
How Flutter codes create apps for about six various platforms?

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview ?

Comment: sure, but I want to know how C Engine works here?

Comment: C is a general programming language which can be compiled to a lot of different platforms. So it is not strange than you can compile this code into all the different platforms which Flutter supports. I am not really sure what question you want to get an answer to since your question are really broad.

Comment: So Dart codes are converted to C codes? and then C codes create multi-platform apps?

Comment: Dart code is compiled into native CPU instructions. But Flutter and Dart does not consist only of Dart code but does also have a layer of C and C++ code which is what the linked article are trying to explain. So in short, the Dart code you are writing will be compiled into native CPU instructions by the Dart compiler which supports compiling Dart code into multiple platforms. The compiled program will then be linked against a native bundle made in C and C++ which provides the runtime for your application (e.g. garbage collection).

Comment: Thank you, would you plz write your comment in the Answer section? Because other users can easily read it.

Answer (score 4):

The Flutter project is are combination of components written in different programming languages. For details about each layer, I recommend looking at the figure at:
https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#architectural-layers

The framework, and most of your own app code, are written in Dart which are then compiled using the Dart compiler from the Dart SDK. This compiler supports multiple targets (both CPU's and operating systems) and is able to compile the code into native CPU instructions (x86, x86_64, ARM64, RISC-V and more) or transpile to JavaScript.

The "Engine" is written in C and C++ which are both programming languages that can be compiled into a lot of platforms. The engine comes precompiled (for all supported platforms) with the Flutter project and is therefore more a binary library which your code can make use of.

Flutter then consists of platform specific code in the "Embedder" layer which is written in different programming languages depending on the target platform. From the previous linked articled:

> The embedder is written in a language that is appropriate for the platform: currently Java and C++ for Android, Objective-C/Objective-C++ for iOS and macOS, and C++ for Windows and Linux.

You could say that this is the actual code that is needed to be written differently for each supported platform where the other layers can stay close to the same (While still needed to be compiled to the target platform). This code comes also precompiled as part of the Flutter framework.

When you compile your application, Flutter will use all of this to bundle up and application that can then be executed on a given target platform.